# Unable to perform for loop on json response object

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I have dictionary of categories & their types in .cs file such as

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> jsonDic
```

I have converted it into the json object string using following logic:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string barJson = jss.Serialize(jsonDic);
string js = "TypesArray(" + barJson + ")";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Startup1", js, true);
```

Now, in .js file I am getting following response

[image]

As we can see result is not in the form of array I am not able to index tpoints since it is not an array. What should I do? I want to index categories also types assosiated with each category..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any of the attributes by name

```
 tpoints["Foods"]
```

and that returns you an array of strings, in the foods case

```
[Restaurant, Cafe, Bakery]
```

If you want to iterate,

```
for (var property in tpoints ) {
    if (tpoints.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting very confused with the kind of data structure you're working with. First, you're question title is false...

> Unable to perform for loop on json response object

because you are indeed looping through the json objects. When you serialize the object below...

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> jsonDic;
```

the serializer is actually mapping each `KeyValuePair` object inside the dictionary to a json array item, that is `tPoint`. So, to iterate through this array all you have to do is the following...

```
for (var tpoint in tpoints ) {
    tpoint.Foods; //get food array
    tpoint.Foods[0]; //get the first food item

}
```

and so on, you could even add a nested `for` loop to iterate through each inner array as below...

```
for (var tpoint in tpoints ) {

    for(var i = 0; i < tpoint.Foods.length;i++){
        console.log(tpoint.Foods[i]);
    }
}
```

this will iterate through all food items in every `tpoints`